# Laravel 5.5.44 project which is downloaded from the server for more developments

Tags: laravel, path, console, laravel-5.5

I have downloaded a **Laravel 5.5.44** project from the **c panel** for further developments. When uploading this project before few months ago the person who had uploaded had been taken files from the ***public folder into c panel's public html folder***. So that after I downloaded the project and I have create a folder named ``public and moved all required files from c panel public html folder.Also i have changed `index.php` as follow.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php' ;
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php' ;
```

Then I start the server via port 8000. But the site is loading with `404 errors` in **console**.[image: This is console]

This is my folder structure
[image: Current folder structure]

This is the code for images

```
@foreach($banners as $banner)
                @if($banner->type == 'Slide 1')
                    <img src="{{asset('uploads')}}/{{$banner->name}}" alt="Compare Prices In Sri Lanka"/>
                @endif
                @if($banner->type == 'Slide 2')
                    <img src="{{asset('uploads')}}/{{$banner->name}}" alt="Price Comparison Website In Sri Lanka"/>
                @endif
                @if($banner->type == 'Slide 3')
                    <img src="{{asset('uploads')}}/{{$banner->name}}" alt="Prices in Sri Lanka"/>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

Could anyone please help me on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Public folder in your laravel root directory. Then move all your assets files from the public_html folder to that folder (Laravel Public Folder). Then check again. Should be loaded all assets.